# Determining if a function is onto or one-to-one

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $P$ be the power set of $\{a,b,c\}$. A function $f: P \to \mathbb Z$;the set of integers, follows: For
$A$ in $P$, $f(A)$=the number of elements in $A$.

I'm not sure how to get started with this problem and would appreciate any hints as to solving it.

Here is the powerset:

$\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$

Comment: Hint for how to get started: write down the definitions of every technical term.

Comment: This is small enough that you can write out the function explicitly for each subset of $\{a,b,c\}$. That might help you a lot.

Comment: @Johanna I've written out the powerset but I don't understand how to check for one-to-one or onto?  Since the first 4 sets are not ordered pairs, are these just considered part of the domain with no mapping to the co-domain? Are each of the sets considered functions or is the entire set the function?  Sorry for all the questions

Comment: @inquisitor What is the definition of one-to-one? What is the definition of onto?

Comment: @Johanna one-to-one means that every element of the domain maps to exactly one element of the co-domain.  Onto means every element in the co-domain maps to at least one member in the domain.

Comment: @inquisitor Another way of stating it is that one-to one means that if two elements map to the same point in the co-domain, then they are equal. Are there two distinct elements in your power set that have the same image? For onto, is there any integer which does not correspond to the size of a subset?

Comment: @Johanna yes, $\{a,c\}$ and $\{b,c\}$, I don't understand the second part.

Comment: Is there an $ A $ such that $ f(A) = 99 $?  If not, it cannot be onto.  Is $ f(\{a\}) = f(\{b\}) $? If it is, it cannot be one-to-one.

Comment: @inquisitor So now you know that the function is not one-to-one. For the second part, pick say the element $10 \in \mathbb{Z}$. If the function is onto, then there is some subset which maps to $10$. Is there?

Comment: @inquisitor Also, it seems like you are having issues with understanding the basic concepts. I would suggest reading over the section in your book again, and maybe going to see your lecturer or TA. They can help more than a stranger on the internet when you are having issues with something this fundamental.

Comment: @Johanna, I think I understand the basic concepts fine, it's just that I'm taking an online class and, there is no lecture and there are no blackboard examples or anything that I can logically follow the steps.  So while the concepts make sense, I'm not really sure how to apply them.

Comment: @inquisitor Does you understand now why the function is neither one-to-one nor onto? Also, check out these links http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function#Examples http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function#Examples

Comment: @Johanna I think so, and thanks so much for your patience and willingness to help.

Comment: @inquisitor No problem :)

Comment: @Johanna for onto, it is correct to say that this function is not onto because no elements of $\mathbb Z$ exist as elements of the of the power set (or domain).  I just want to check my understanding.

Comment: @inquisitor No. The function is not onto because there exist elements the codomain $\mathbb{Z}$ (eg: 10, 99, anything negative or larger than 3) that no elements of the domain map to. Take a look at the links I put in an earlier comment, especially the one about surjective (onto) functions.

Comment: @Johanna wow I see the simplicity in this now.

Comment: @inquisitor Great!

Comment: @Johannai had the lightbulb moment lol. :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For one-to-one: can you find two elements $x,y$ of $P$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$?
2. For onto: can *every* integer number be written in the form $f(x)$ for some $x\in P$? If not, say a concrete example.

Comment: So the power set would contain $2^3$ elements or $8$ elements.  Does this mean that I'm determining if the power set of the above set contains elements which make the function onto or one-to-one?